# Query posts by category, when category contains multiple categories?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, categories

I have a database, that contains movies and every movie post `category` field is written this way: `8, 12, 16`. This means, that movie is Action and Drama and etc. This is what I'm doing:

```
$fields = "id, xfields, category";
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `dle_post` WHERE `category` IN ($subcatsStr) ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT :from, :to");
$query->bindParam(":from", $from);
$query->bindParam(":to", $count);
$query->execute();
```

So now I want to get all movies, that are action movies(category ID: 8). `subcatsStr` look like this:

```
$subcatsStr = "8";
```

Query finds only movies, that `category` starts with 8, e.g. movie, which `category` is `8,12,47,53` or `8,11,12,17,53`. But when `category` is e.g `12,8`, it doesn't find it. How can I make it work as I want?

**EDIT:**
I noticed `find_in_set` works only when `subcatsStr` is a single digit, e.g `8`, but it doesn't, when it's e.g `8, 12, 16, 19`. When user selects top category(e.g. movies), `subcatsStr` contains many values, that are categories and subcategories. Solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM dle_post 
WHERE find_in_set('$subcatsStr', category) > 0
```

But actually it would be better to change your table design. Never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: "Never store multiple values in one column!" Repeated for emphasis.

Comment: I updated my answer, it actually doesn't work well when `subcatsStr` contains more than 1 value.

Comment: A slight thing is to change. FIND_IN_SET expects a list separated only by comma. You've got a trailing blank after your comma, so we must remove this first: `WHERE find_in_set('$subcatsStr', REPLACE(category, ' ', '')) > 0` But the main issue is: Never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: @VMai yeah, but it does not help when `subcatsStr` contains more than 1 value, like `1,2,3`. See edit in question.

Comment: Ok, so you have a comma separated list of values too.

Comment: @VMai yeah, I need something like `find_in_set`, but for multiple values. Can you offer a solution?

Comment: @Gintas_: Can you split up your `$subcatsStr`? If so, you can use multiple `find_in_set()` in your query.

Comment: @Gintas_ Is it sufficient if any value of your $subcatsStr is in the categories or is it needed that all of them are in the categories list. But let's repeat: Change your table design, if you can.

Comment: @VMai I cannot. It's needed, that any value of $subcatsStr is in the categories.

Comment: @Gintas_ That's too bad. Then I propose you do as juergen has said: split the string and build AND conditions with the parts.